# twilio composition taking 15, 20 minutes or more status Enqueued

Tags: twilio

We are prototyping a twilio video solution where we need to record via a webcam, from a conference room and wish to have an mp4 video (mkv and mka combined) available in near real time.

When we are using twilio compositions , the mp4 is listed as “Enqueued” status for a long time - like over 15 minutes  The Mkv and Mk4 are near instantly available.  How much time the composition process takes to complete ?

Are we not closing the room properly to cause this? We are calling stop recording.

Answer (score 1):

[Creating Compositions with Twilio Programmable Video](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046032033-Creating-Compositions-with-Twilio-Programmable-Video)

Compositions delays: A good rough estimate for compositions to process is half the time of the original recordings. Once a composition has been requested, it cannot be removed or re-enqueued. You will need to wait until the composition is completed in order to remove it. At this time, Twilio does not have an SLA or maximum time for compositions to complete. Under peak load, it is possible that compositions may be in the queue for a few hours.